# Conveniently SSH to internal hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, lan, port-forwarding

I recently discovered that with `~/.ssh/config`, I can save a lot of keystrokes and automate long command lines, specifying a lot of per-host defaults. Now that I noticed how powerful the tool can be, I am wondering if it can fit another of my use cases.

I have access to two hosts, `bastion` and `wikispy`. Bastion has an external IP, `wikispy` is only visible from the internal one. This means that normally in order to connect to `wikispy`, I need to ssh to `bastion` first and then call `ssh wikispy`. Obviously things like port forwarding are going to be complicated this way and this is something I would like to avoid.

This leads to a question: can I somehow make `~/.ssh/config` entry that would tell "when the user requests host labeled `wikispy`, actually connect to `bastion`, then call `ssh wikispy`"? Would it be possible to work transparently so that I could call things like `ssh wikispy -L 9999:localhost:9999` and have `bastion` forward the port in a way that would let me access it from inside of `wikispy`?

Comment: `inf` from `#hackerspace-pl@irc.freenode.net` pointed me there: http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is where a combination of `ProxyCommand` and `nc` proves useful. Here's a solution - add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bastion
HostName EXTERNAL_IP
User d

Host wikispy
HostName INTERNAL_IP
User d
ProxyCommand ssh bastion nc -q0 %h 22
```

According to [this article](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), you can get more than a single level of nesting this way.